# Check jQuery version and load a newer version

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have various web pages that have varying versions of jQuery included on them ranging from 1.4.2 upwards (yes, I know, it's a mess).  I want to use the jQuery validation plugin on these pages but it requires jQuery 1.6.4+.

I know I can check the version of jQuery loaded and then load in a newer version if necessary but I'm unsure on how to reference them individually so the pre-existing JavaScript/jQuery code that's on the site can still use $ (as I know this works quite happily and I don't want to break it) and then the new plugin can use something else?

Any help or suggestions on a better way to do this would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Seems a little dangerous swapping out version of jQuery on the fly...what if the new version breaks code that relies on the old version?

Comment: "and then load in a newer version if necessary" - don't do this.  Only one jQuery should be loaded, or prepare to expect the unexpected...  Test out the newer jQuery in a qa/staging area, and then switch over when everything is deemed working.  And if you have a JS testsuite, all the better for you.

Comment: I would not recommend to do that. You should use a layout where all the main includes are the same for all your pages. Or use a header file.

Comment: I'm not trying to swap out I'm trying to run concurrently.  So old code runs "as was" referencing $ and the plugin runs referencing a newer version of jQuery somehow.  I've seen it done with two versions of jQuery but then you reference both versions differently and I don't want to change any existing code to reference jQuery not using the dollar sign (hope that makes sense?).

Comment: The route you are going seems hackish. Yeah, possible as it may be, using a newer version and adjusting the existing code using a single version of jQuery is the safest route, not to mention that jquery moves forward making code more efficient than it was. I only see positives in updating instead of trying to handle unneeded exception cases

Comment: @everyone - I completely agree with what everyone is saying and I'd much rather be using one newer version across the site but it's huge and we're not in a position resource or time wise to make a switch and test all of the existing code hence this somewhat "hackish" way of doing things.

Comment: Can you be bothered to read the documentation for the library you are using before asking questions like this? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: The top four results from a google search will also give you the information you need..

Answer (score 2):

Bad idea to do what you are doing.

If you really insist on having different jquery versions, you can always write some sort of a script manager. Basically you specify in your page's "config" what jquery versions are required on this page and the manager will load the appropriate one.

Something like:

```
// each page content before everything else
Manager.reguire("plugin 1", "1.4.7");
Manager.require("plugin 2", "1.4.4");


// Main layout <head section>
Manager.LoadRequiredVersions();
```

And the manager would just  request the files for you, but don't forget that you might have to do some clever no-conflict stuff with jQuery if you want more than one on a single page. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1566644/486780

If it's one version per page then a manager would be the easiest option.

Answer (score 1):

- original version of jquery loads (Version1)

  - $ and jQuery belong to version1
- second version of jquery loads (Verion2)

  - now $ and jQuery belong to Version2, and _$ and _jQuery that belongs to Version1
- assign the Version2 version to a var ($v2 = jQuery.noConflict(true);)

  - now $ and jQuery belong to Version1, _$ and _jQuery are probably null, and $v2 is Version2